# How to get genre list from Google Books?

Tags: python, google-books

I want to get all the genres in Google Books and list them on my website, and then I want to search for books based on multiple genres.

Currently, I'm searching within a single genre. When I provide multiple genres in the Google Books Volume API, it does not work as expected.

Comment: Can you show the code you got so far?

Comment: I need google books API, which sends all the genre listing. I don't think my codes need here

Comment: Any success with this?